# How do I clone a private repo to my single user notebook server?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I'm deploying jupyterhub on a Google Kubernetes cluster
and I want the single user spawner to clone a private repo when being initialized.

I've tried to use a personal token from github using the repo scope.
and modified my postStart command to:

```
command: ["gitpuller", "https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<organization>/<repo>.git", "master", "MyRepo"]
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Stefan no...sorry

Comment: Here is what worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485967/how-to-init-content-of-notebooks-working-directory-in-jupyterhub-jupyterlab/64493570#64493570

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer and Prerequisites

I'm fairly new to the world of GKE and JupyterHub. There may be better methods and practices than those I describe here. My setup is based on an Ubuntu 22.04 machine, so the instructions will reflect that. However, the type of machine used to control your GKE should not significantly impact the process.

I assume you have [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) and [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/) set up and are familiar with basic [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) scripting.

## Setting up Helm

[Helm](https://helm.sh/) is a package manager for Kubernetes. Think of [helm charts](https://hub.jupyter.org/helm-chart/) as versions of JupyterHub that allow you to install JupyterHub directly into your Kubernetes cluster. Essentially, you can view these as an API to the Kubernetes API, simplifying the usage and installation of JupyterHubs.

Please check for [up-to-date installation instructions](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/), but here are the steps I followed (requires sudo privileges):

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/HEAD/scripts/get-helm-3 | bash
```

Check if the installation was successful:

```bash
helm version
```

Next, make Helm aware of the JupyterHub Helm chart repository:

```bash
helm repo add jupyterhub https://hub.jupyter.org/helm-chart/
helm repo update
```

Then, create an empty `config.yaml` file. This allows you to customize your JupyterHub. For now, we'll leave it empty and simply ensure we can install a vanilla JupyterHub into GKE. **Replace** the angle-bracketed `<...>` arguments with your own:

```bash
touch config.yaml
helm upgrade --cleanup-on-fail \
  --install <hub-name> jupyterhub/jupyterhub \
  --namespace <k8s-namespace> \
  --create-namespace \
  --version=<version-number> \
  --values </path/to/config.yaml>
```

After running the above command, you should see a message saying:

> You have successfully installed the official JupyterHub Helm chart!

along with other information about your installation.

## Configuring Your Hub to Pull from a Private Repo

### Create a GitHub Deploy Key for Your Private Repo

Start by generating an SSH key without a passphrase:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "<your-github@email.com>" -N "" -f <key-name>
```

Next, add your key to your desired repository. This [GitHub page](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#set-up-deploy-keys) provides steps for adding a deploy key to your repo.
When you add the deploy key, you'll have the option to assign privileges to it. At a minimum, the key should allow you to pull from the private repo.

### Add SSH Key as a Secret to Your Pods

Ensure both your public and private SSH keys are available to each pod on startup by adding them as a secret using the following command:

```bash
kubectl --namespace=<k8s-namespace> create secret generic github-ssh-key --from-file=ssh-privatekey=</path/to/.ssh/key-name> --from-file=ssh-publickey=</path/to/.ssh/key-name.pub>
```

A quick note here. Instead of saying `--from-file=ssh-privatekey=...` you could just say `--from-file=key-name=</path/to/.ssh/key-name`. However, since later on you'll have to copy the key from the secrets folder (root) to the  jovyan home folder (user) the name doesn't matter.

### Create a Startup Script for Clone/Pull Operations

Create a script, named `clone.sh`, to perform your desired Git operations. Below is an example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Force script to always exit successfully
trap "exit 0" EXIT

# Define SHELL variables
CLONE_DIR="/home/jovyan/repo"
USER_SSH_DIR="/home/jovyan/.ssh"
SECRET_DIR="/etc/secret-volume"
LOG_DIR="/home/jovyan/logs"
KNOWN_HOSTS="known_hosts"
SECRET_PRIVATE_KEY="ssh-privatekey"
SECRET_PUBLIC_KEY="ssh-publickey"
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="<key-name>"
SSH_PUBLIC_KEY="<key-name.pub>"

# Check if log dir exists if not create it
if [ ! "$(ls -A $LOG_DIR)" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$LOG_DIR" || true
fi

GIT_LOG_FILE="$LOG_DIR/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')-git.log"

# Check if folder $CLONE_DIR is non-empty and pull repo, else clone repo
if [ "$(ls -A $CLONE_DIR)" ]; then
    chmod 600 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" || true
    chmod 644 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" || true
    chmod 600 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$KNOWN_HOSTS" || true
    cd "$CLONE_DIR" 
    git checkout . > "$GIT_LOG_FILE" 2>&1 || true
    git pull >> "$GIT_LOG_FILE" 2>&1 || true
else
    mkdir -p "$USER_SSH_DIR" || true
    cp "$SECRET_DIR/$SECRET_PRIVATE_KEY" "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" || true
    cp "$SECRET_DIR/$SECRET_PUBLIC_KEY" "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" || true
    chmod 600 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" || true
    chmod 644 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$SSH_PUBLIC_KEY" || true
    ssh-keyscan github.com > "$USER_SSH_DIR/$KNOWN_HOSTS" || true
    chmod 600 "$USER_SSH_DIR/$KNOWN_HOSTS" || true

    mkdir -pv "$CLONE_DIR" || true
    git clone git@github.com:<your-repo-name>.git "$CLONE_DIR" > "$GIT_LOG_FILE" 2>&1 || true
fi
```

Depending on whether you have previously cloned the repo, the script will either checkout and pull or clone from your repo.
Note that the script is designed to always exit successfully. This approach helps in debugging, as the pod will start regardless of the script's failure, allowing you to log into the pod and investigate any issues. If the script fails, you won't be able to create any pods, or at least I didn't find a way to do so.

### Add Your Startup Script as a ConfigMap

Add your script as a config map as follows:

```bash
kubectl --namespace=<k8s-namespace> create configmap pod-scripts --from-file=</path/to/clone.sh>
```

### Create the `config.yaml` and Upgrade Your Helm

Your `config.yaml` file should contain the **Mount secrets and configmaps**, **Ensure Git uses the correct SSH key**, and **Run clone script** sections as shown below:

```yaml
singleuser:
  # User base image (if you have your own docker image)
  image:
    name: <docker-hub-user/image-name>
    tag: <image-tag>
    pullPolicy: Always # Useful if you make frequent updates to the docker image
  # Needed for authentication to work with GKE Autopilot https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/experiences-with-gke-autopilot/9405/2
  cloudMetadata:
    blockWithIptables: false
  # Mount secrets and configmaps
  storage:
    extraVolumes:
      - name: ssh-key
        secret:
          secretName: github-ssh-key
      - name: scripts-vol
        configMap:
          name: pod-scripts
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: ssh-key
        mountPath: "/etc/secret-volume"
        readOnly: true
      - name: scripts-vol
        mountPath: "/scripts"
  # Ensure git uses correct ssh-key
  extraEnv:
    GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "ssh -i /home/jovyan/.ssh/<key-name>"
  # Run clone script
  lifecycleHooks:
    postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["sh", "/scripts/clone.sh"]
```

Once you have updated your `config.yaml` as shown above, run the `helm upgrade` command for the changes to take effect:

```bash
helm upgrade --cleanup-on-fail  <hub-name> jupyterhub/jupyterhub   --namespace <k8s-namespace> --version=<version-number>   --values </path/to/config.yaml>
```

Hope this helps!