# How do you authenticate into private github repos from Jupyter Hub on Kubernetes

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

We have deployed JupyterHub to Kubernetes. I am trying to understand how git authentication would work in this environment. For example, our users need to push and pull from a private github repo to persist notebook files. What would be the best practice for this? Ideally, we would not want the user to enter their user / password every time they do a push or pull from a private repo. Here are the options we are considering:

- Have the user upload their ssh keys to the container where the Jupyter Notebook server is running.
- Similarly, install a git credential manager along with JupyterHub on the Kubernetes Pod like https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager and have them their persist their creds using that.
- Another person suggested that you could use OIDC when authenticating into the Jupyter Hub pod to also authenticate to Git, and then use that auth. Is that a viable approach? In that flow it's not clear to me how Git would access the auth creds when doing the git operations (from either the Jupyter Notebook extension or the command line) But it would be great if there's a way it could be automatic and the user would not need to go through the extra step of storing their credentials in the pod.

Are any of the above the recommended option, or is there another approach we should consider? Thanks.

I have run JupyterHub and tried the SSH key approach, though it is made trickier by the fact that I couldn't copy and paste from my clipboard to the server command line (even though I enabled it in Chrome).

Comment: Cross-posted without acknowledgement [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/best-practice-for-authenticating-interacting-with-private-github-repos-from-jupyter-hub-on-kubernetes/20940?u=fomightez). Those interested may want to look there as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Disclaimer and Prerequisites

I'm fairly new to the world of Kubernetes and JupyterHub. There may be better methods and practices than those I describe here.

I assume you have [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/) set up and are familiar with basic [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) scripting.

## Things to Consider

Before delving into the main topics, let's discuss how users can avoid typing their password every time they interact with a private Git repository.

### Interacting with a Private Repo Without Password Authentication

To eliminate the need for password input during every push/pull from a private repo, you will need some sort of key installed both on the GitHub server and in your local environment. The question then becomes: should each user use their own SSH key for repository interactions, or can they use a single deploy key? Using a deploy key is practical only if all users are working on the same private repo.

### Options to Consider

1. Are your users interacting with one private repo, or does each user need to interact with a different private repo?
2. If your users are interacting with the same private repo, you have a couple of options:

   - Install a deploy key in each pod that gives access to the repo.
   - Have each user install their own SSH key in their pod (and give them access to your private repo).
3. If each user needs access to their own private repo (i.e., each user has access to a different repo), the only viable option is for each user to install their own SSH key in their respective pods.

## Installing One Deploy Key for All Users

Please check out this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77545947/1459061) for more information.

## Having Each User Install Their Own SSH Key

The simplest way for users to copy their SSH keys is to use the `kubectl cp` command as follows:

```bash
kubectl cp <local-ssh-key-path> <namespace>/<pod-name>:<remote-path>
```

Users must also ensure that `git` uses the correct SSH command. They can do this by setting the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable:

```bash
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i <remote-path>/<key-name>"
```

To make this available system-wide, add the following line to the pod's local `.bashrc` file:

```bash
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i <remote-path>/<key-name>"
```

Alternatively, you can add it to your `.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: <image-name>
    command: ["<command>"]
    env:
    - name: GIT_SSH_COMMAND
      value: "ssh -i <remote-path>/<key-name>"
```

### Using `kubectl cp`

For users to copy files to a specific pod using the `kubectl cp` command, the following permissions are required:

- Read permission on the pod's namespace.
- Write permission on the pod's container.

If you are using RBAC (Role-Based Access Control), create a custom role that grants these permissions and then assign the role to the user executing the `kubectl cp` command. For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-copier
  namespace: default
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["apps"]
  resources: ["deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: ["."]
  resources: ["configmaps", "secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

To assign this role to a user, use the following command:

```bash
kubectl create rolebinding <rolebinding-name> --clusterrole=pod-copier --user=<user-name>
```

With the appropriate permissions assigned, your users will be able to copy files to pods using the `kubectl cp` command.

Hope this helps!